# Import EML files into Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, mbox

I have few "text files" of mail messages, they contains headers and mail messages in HTML. They were generated by md2mb.py tool when converting from MailDir to MBOX.

It contains many of these lines:

> This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>
> ------_=_NextPart_001_01D1EF1E.7EBE7F58

Answer (score -2):

These are EML files. You can use many tools to import these files into Outlook. For example, using the free [Import Messages from EML Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesImportEML/) utility created by me.

Comment: thanks, your app really helps